# spring integratoin and mongo compatibility

Tags: spring, mongodb, integration, compatibility

I'm using spring integration in my projeect, and have another project for making querys in `MongoDB`, i'm using `Maven`, and spring boot, so i java configuration file in my Mongo Proect like this:

```
   @Autowired
      Environment environment;



@Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("mongo.uri"));
        MongoClientURI uri=new MongoClientURI(environment.getProperty("mongo.uri"));
        System.out.println("------");
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(uri), "test");
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("mongoTemplate()");

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());

        return mongoTemplate;

    }
}
```

In my integration project I use this pom.xml depenency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>

</dependency>
```

And when i run  my Application.class get this error

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/MongoClient;Ljava/lang/String
```

If i Add as suggested in other questions this dependency:

```
.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory'
```

Any Sugestions?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with the version of the mongodb